# Objective-C: What's the difference between @[ ] and [[NSArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0]

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmutablearray, objective-c-literals

I have a method to build and return an array:

```
- (NSArray *)foo 
{
    NSUInteger capacity = [self getArrayCapacity];
    if (capacity == 0) {
        return @[];
    } else {
        NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:capacity];
        // add elements to the array, as many as capacity 
        ...
        return array;
    }
}
```

Is there a difference in memory used or performance if I simplify the code as follows:

```
- (NSArray *)fooSimplified 
{
    NSUInteger capacity = [self getCapacity];
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:capacity];
        // add elements to the array, as many as capacity 
        ...
        return array;
    }
}
```

So when `capacity == 0` instead of returning `@[]` it would return `[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0]`

Is there a performance or memory penalty/difference?

Comment: Can't you test that yourself? You can call it in a loop a million times and see if the speed is different between the 2. You can use Instruments to see if there's a difference in memory size. Also, does the immediate syntax create a mutable or immutable instance? My reading of the docs only shows immutable creation.

Comment: Don't prefix getters with `get` (objc doesn't use the `get` prefix generally).

Answer (score 1):

```
[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0]
```

This will create a mutable array and allocate memory that is enough to hold specified number of elements, so it can by any high enough number depending on implementation.

```
@[]
```

Is optimized to return an instance of __NSArray0 class which is the same instance each time you create it, so there's no extra memory allocations in this case.

So using `@[]` is more optimal, however you probably won't see real difference unless you call this function very frequently.

Running some benchmarks in iOS simulator:

```
NSLog(@"%llu", dispatch_benchmark(100, ^{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {
      NSArray *a = @[];
    }
  }));

NSLog(@"%llu", dispatch_benchmark(100, ^{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {
      NSArray *a = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
    }
  }));


 Array Literal: 9835575 ns
 Mutable Array: 157169503 ns
```

Comment: Minor point;  `initWithCapacity:` doesn't necessarily pre-allocate the space.  It just hints to the mutable array how memory should potentially be optimally managed.